# 500 error:HTML created in coded not getting downloaded in servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have written a web application which takes input from the user via a web form and based on that inputs changes a particular html file and creates a new one and saves it in webContent folder of dynamic Web Project.I have a sample.txt file also put into that folder but its not created in the code its something placed for testing.It gets downlaoded as needed but the created HTML file gives a 500 error with Null pointer exception in reading the bytes in the code.
The snippet is as follows

```
String filepath = "/Users/schhatre13/Documents/workspace/CustomHTMLTool/WebContent/"+"customHTML.html";
        File downloadedFile = new File(filepath);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(downloadedFile));
        bw.write(html);
        bw.close();

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                         "attachment;filename=customHTML"+new Date()+".html");
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/customHTML.html");
        int read=0;
        //i++;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
```

The error thrown is a 500 Internal Server error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    HTMLCustomizer.doGet(HTMLCustomizer.java:160)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

This is in the line

```
while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1){
```

i.e the Null poinnter exception. I don't understand the problem because my manually placed .txt file gets downloaded as required.

Thanks
Swaraj

Comment: NPE has identified itself in the console. Did you check it?

Comment: @Octopus Thanks for the prompt reply but I didn't get NPE??.

Comment: Debug and see what's null.

Comment: NPE = NullPointerException

Comment: NPE - null pointer exception -- welcome :)

Comment: @Taylor read = is.read(bytes) is null for HTML file created in the code itself but not null for the text file placed manually.

Comment: Flush where you are creating your html file. Close all objects that are used to write to the file.

Comment: What is null? `is`?  IF so, that probably means you're not laoding the file correctly.  Note that the web content dir can be different from what you expect and some servers copy the webapp folder on startup.  I'd suggest writting and reading the file relatively if at all possible or use some programmatic way to determine the file path to the web dir.

Comment: @Taylor read = is.read(bytes) is null.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre that doesn't make sense.  Is `read` null or `is`?

Comment: @Taylor Thanks a lot yes the webApplication folder has a different path.There are a few hidden folders to be taken care of like /Users/schhatre13/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CustomHTMLTool/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is null? `is`? If so, that probably means you're not loading the file correctly. Note that the web content dir can be different from what you expect and some servers copy the webapp folder on startup. I'd suggest writing and reading the file relatively if at all possible or use some programmatic way to determine the file path to the web dir.